# using sqlite with python, fetchall()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to compare a list of links to the liks stored in an sqlite database.

assuming the links in the database are:

> link.com\page1
>
> link.com\page2
>
> link.com\page3

I have written the following code to chick if a given link exists in the database and adds it if it did not exist.

```
links = ['link.com\page2', 'link.com\page4']
c.execute('SELECT link FROM ads')
previouslinks = c.fetchall()

for l in links:
    if l not in previouslinks:
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO ads(link) VALUES(?)''', (l))
        conn.commit()
    else:
        pass
```

the problem is even though the link is in the database, the script does not recognise it!

when I try to print `previouslinks` variable, results look something like this:

```
[('link.com\page1',), ('link.com\page2',), ('link.com\page3',)]
```

I think the problem  is with the extra parentheses and commas, but I am not exactly sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` returns a list of rows, where each row is a tuple containing all column values. A tuple containing a string is not the same as the string.

You have to extract the values from the rows (and you don't need `fetchall()` when iterating over a cursor):

```
previouslinks = [row[0] for row in c]
```